# Injecting data into Docusign Document that all recipients can see

Tags: docusignapi

I want to create a docusign template with one document in it. When I create a recipient view, I want to inject data that all recipients of the doc can see. I thought creating custom fields would have helped in that, but each custom field gets assigned to certain role and only recipient with that role sees the data I inject. I want all recipients to see. How can I achieve this? It is almost like I want document tabs that belong to the document, but not particular role.

Comment: I discovered that whatever custom tabs get added for the first recipient in route order, that data becomes visible to all subsequent recipients.

Answer (score 0):

One other way you can do that is by replacing the document that will be sent to all recipients in your code. You can still use the same template, you can still use the tabs that were originally defined, but the document can be dynamically modified before you send out the envelope. 
I would encourage you to consider using a composite template for this scenario as it will make things more flexible when you need to make future enhancements.
Here are two resources on this topic:

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-why-use-composite-templates/

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-adding-document-template